# Getting an error in C: passing argument 1 of function from incompatible pointer type

Tags: c, function, pointers, struct, dereference

The function signature is

```
void abort(context_t **ctx);
```

, where `ctx` is a property of another struct.

After I have created a pointer to the main struct ( `server_t *server` ), I can pass the pointer to the pointer to the main struct ( `**server` ) around with no problem, using the pointers to its properties like this: `(*server)->ctx` or `(*server)->addr`, etc.

But I cannot figure out how to pass the `**ctx` to a function directly, without passing the `**server`. If I try it as `abort(&server->ctx)`, I get an error:

```
error: passing argument 1 of ‘abort’ from incompatible pointer type: abort(&server->ctx);

note: expected ‘context_t ** {aka struct context_t **}’ but argument is of type ‘struct context_t *’

void abort(context_t **ctx);
```

Comment: Hello. I was wondering if someone could tell me what's wrong with this post so that I can edit and improve it? Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> note: expected ‘context_t ** {aka struct context_t **}’ but argument is of type ‘struct context_t *’

It seems you try to assign pointer to double pointer. You can try:

```
context_t * temp_ctx = &server->ctx;
abort(&temp_ctx);
```

Answer (score 1):

The compiler error can be fixed by the following lines of codes:

```
/* declare context_t* pointer variable on the appropriate scope */
/* based on how **ctx is used by abort() */
context_t *pContext;

/* .... */

/* assign the pointer */
pContext = &server->ctx;

/* now pass the context_t** or "the address of pContext" to abort() */
abort(&pContext);
```